# Update sql query with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table in my database.

```
xcart_product_mmy_items xcart_products
```

in **xcart_products** i have two column

```
productid productsku
```

Some sample data:-

```
productid  productsku
123        AAA
456        BBB
789        CCC
012        DDD
```

and in my **xcart_product_mmy_items** i have three column

```
id   productid   skuid
```

Some sample data:-

```
id productid  skuid 
1  012 
2  789 
3  456
4  123
```

i want to update the **skuid** of **xcart_product_mmy_items** according to **xcart_products.productsku**

So the result of xcart_product_mmy_items table will be

```
id  productid  skuid
1   012        DDD
2   789        CCC
3   456        BBB
4   123        AAA
```

i tried that sql query

```
UPDATE MAIN
SET MAIN.skuid = SUB.productsku
FROM xcart_product_mmy_items MAIN
INNER JOIN xcart_products SUB ON MAIN.productid = SUB.productid
```

But i dont know where i am wrong..
Please Help me..

Comment: Why do you denormalize your model like this? Why not join `xcart_products` if you need the `skuid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
UPDATE xcart_product_mmy_items MAIN
  INNER JOIN xcart_products SUB ON MAIN.productid = SUB.productid
SET MAIN.skuid = SUB.productsku
```